# Get inside Javascript object in "for" loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I need to get **lat** and **lng** inside **list**. I have something like this and don't know how to get these values.

```
  var list = {
    "punkt1": {
    "lat": 49.834390,
    "lng": 19.068899
    },
    "punkt2": {
    "lat": 49.834990,
    "lng": 19.068199
    }
  };

  var count = Object.keys(list).length;

  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    // Get inside list[i] -> lat,lng
    // If statement
  }
```

Comment: Use `for..in` to loop over objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a few ways, here are two:

```js
  var list = {
    "punkt1": {
    "lat": 49.834390,
    "lng": 19.068899
    },
    "punkt2": {
    "lat": 49.834990,
    "lng": 19.068199
    }
  };

  var count = Object.keys(list).length;

  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    var currObj = list[Object.keys(list)[i]];
    console.dir(currObj);
  }

for (item in list){
  console.log(item);
  console.dir(list[item]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But why "for" loop shows me only 1 item if I have two items in my list?

Comment: which loop is showing that? If I check my console output it shows two for each

Comment: Oh I know why it doesn't work. After posting I named "punkt1" and "punkt2" just "punkt". Now I've changed to "punkt1" and "punkt2". Eveything works now!

Comment: awesome, glad to hear it's working